# Share Git repository directory across multiple build definitions

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a private agent build starts in VSTS, it gets assigned a directory, e.g. C:\vstsagent_work\1\s

Is there a way to set this to a different path?  On other CI servers, like Jenkins, I can define a custom workspace for a job.  I'm dealing with a huge monorepo and have dozens of build definitions around the same repository.  It makes sense (to me anyway) to share a single directory on the build agent computer.

The benefit to me is that my builds can use pre-built components from upstream repositories, if they have already been built.

Thanks for any help

Comment: own agent or private agent?

Comment: Have you looked at Nuget `packageReference` in Visual Studio 2017.3+? That allows you to set a version spec that will just take latest or allows you to use MsBuild properties to set the same version as your own project for the references.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I'm using private agents.  I'd really rather not go the nuget route, again.  I got burned badly last time the complexity it takes to manage that.  I want to keep things simple, and the current approach is simple, unfortunately inefficient.

Comment: Are you setting the Assembly version during build? Do you have one or multiple build definitions? Each build definition has its own workspace and starts with an older version of the dependencies. If it's one build definitions with a lot of conditionals, it should be redirected to the same workspace/repo every time.

Comment: You can turn off the fetch sources step and invoke `git.exe` or `tf.exe` as the first step of your build. That way you have total control over the location, but you have to do it manually.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I have multiple build definitions.  Your last comment is the direction I'm leaning.  Feel free to write this up as an actual answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS build always creates a working directory per build definition. This leaves you two options:

1. Create a single build definition and use conditionals on steps to skip certain steps in order to only run what is needed. This allows you to use the standard steps and may require a powershell script to figure out which steps to run and which ones to skip. Set variables from powershell using the special logging commands.
2. Disable the get sources step and add a step that manually fetches sources. You'll need to clean the working directory, checkout the right commit, basically replicating the actions in the get sources step manually. It may require some fidgeting to get all the behavior correctly for normal build, pull request builds etc. That way you can take full control over the location where sources are checked out.

I'd also recommend you investigate the 2017 project formats that use the new `<packageReference>` in the project files to fetch packages. The new system supports configuring a version range which can always fetch the latest available version of packages. It's a better long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn’t available in VSTS build system.

You can change working directory of agent (C:\vstsagent_work) (Re-configure it and specify another working folder), but it won’t uses the same source folder for different build definitions, the folder would be 1, 2, 3 ….